# how to join 2 lines using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file that have unknown number of lines , some lines begins with patterns , I want to join the lines that begins with patterns with the next line , so for example

```
name=jimmy
age=19 id=23423 site=www.xxx.com
bla bla
name=katy
age=15 id=234543 site=www.yyy.com
name=ross
age=29 id=54564 site=www.ZZZZ.com
```

the output should be

```
name=jimmy age=19 id=23423 site=www.xxx.com
 bla bla bla
name=katy age=15 id=234543 site=www.yyy.com
name=ross age=29 id=54564 site=www.ZZZZ.com
```

so the pattern is 'name' and it should join next line
I thougt to use sed but I dont know how 
help please

Comment: to be honest , i didnt try anything , I am facing a problem in processing the text file , so I thought that joining the two lines will solve the problem , I am doing a loop , im parsing file text line by line  so read a line then send it to do other stuff , problem that I want to merge the two lines so i can do them in one loop , maybe my explanation wasn't clear :) so ask me if you have doubts , by the way sed should do that but it hards to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's a straightforward script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "INPUT_FILE=input.txt"
set "OUTPUT_FILE=output.txt"
set prev=
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (%INPUT_FILE%) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%g in ("%%f") do (
        if "!prev!" neq "" (
            echo !prev! %%f >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
            set prev=
        ) else (
            if "%%g" equ "name" (
                set prev=%%f
            ) else (
                echo %%f >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
                set prev=
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set pattern=name
set patternLen=4
call :ProcessFile < input.txt > output.txt
goto :EOF

:ProcessFile
set line=
set /P line=
if not defined line exit /B
if "!line:~0,%patternLen%!" equ "%pattern%" (
   set /P nextLine=
   set "line=!line! !nextLine!"
)
echo !line!
goto ProcessFile
```

Previous Batch file have the problem that it ends at the first empty line in the input file. However, this problem may be fixed if needed.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work with me , it gave me the same input

Comment: Ops! Yes, I had a small error (pattern len is 4, no 3). Please, note that to change the pattern by _any other_ one, you just need to change `pattern` and `patternLen` strings. This program does not require the pattern be delimited with equal-sign, that is, you indicated "the pattern is 'name'", not "the pattern is delimited by '='".