# Batch - Combine two lines and add comma to reformat txt to csv

Tags: batch-file

I'm have some formatted text that looks like this:

> 5
>   4294967296
>   4
>   4294967296
>   2
>   4294967296
>   2
>   4294967296
>   2
>   4294967296

I want to make this into a .csv file where every two lines are joined together, like this:

> 5,4294967296
>   4,4294967296
>   2,4294967296
>   2,4294967296
>   2,4294967296

How can I do this in batch? I know how to read in and out files, and all I really need to do is change .txt to .csv. I'm just stuck on how to combine the lines in batch.

I realize [how to join 2 lines using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284732/how-to-join-2-lines-using-batch-file) is kinda similar, but that answer searched for a text pattern, which I don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "file=D:\bat\files\30356343"
set "line="
(for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G in ("%file%.txt") do (
    if defined line (
        echo !line!,%%G
        set "line="
    ) else (
        set "line=%%G"
    )
))>"%file%.csv"

rem show results
ECHO ON
type "%file%.txt"
type "%file%.csv"
```

**Output**:

```
==>type "D:\bat\files\30356343.txt"
5
4294967296
4
4294967297
2
4294967298
2
4294967299

==>type "D:\bat\files\30356343.csv"
5,4294967296
4,4294967297
2,4294967298
2,4294967299

==>
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a Linux machine, so I can't test it but it should be something like this

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set COUNT=0
set even_odd = 1

for /f %%c in ("file.txt") do (
  set /A count=%count% + 1
  set /A even_odd=%count% %% 2
  :: First line is odd (1), ever other is even (0)
  if "%even_odd%" == "1" (
     echo %%c>> file.csv
     echo ,>> file.csv
     :: Odd line: Write the line to the CSV, plus a comma
  ) else (
     echo %%c>> file.csv
     echo.>> file.csv
     :: Even line: Write the line to the CSV, plus a line break
  )
)
```

Comment: the basic logic is ok, but on windows, each `echo` produces an additional linefeed, so you can't build up a single line with several `echo`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :sub < input.txt > output.csv
goto :EOF

:sub
set /P "line="
:nextPair
   set /P "line=%line%,"
   set /P "line=%line%"
   echo/
if "%line:~8%" equ "" goto nextPair
exit /B
```